# Pharo: how can I change number of lines per one scroll in Playground?

Tags: pharo

When I scroll with the mouse's scrolling wheel, one turn of the wheel (the minimum step of scrolling) scrolls the text in Playground for approximately 7-8 lines. This is too much; I would like scrolling to be more continuous. How can I change it?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but you shouldn't need to scroll much at all in Smalltalk, hence this probably isn't much of an issue for most Smalltalkers. Put your code in methods rather than workspaces, keep methods short and sweet, and scrolling becomes a non-issue...

Comment: Is it really convenient to put all code in small methods in the case when I am just trying to accomplish one goal (e.g. get data from a social network API and answer a particular question using this data) and do not plan to reuse any of intermediate code? Having all this code in one place (a scrollable page) seems to have several advantages:

1) you can use one set of variables throughout all your code (while in methods you have to maintain in your mind a correspondence between parameters names inside a method and variables you passed as arguments when sending a message from outside)

Comment: 2) you see all your code in chronological order and can quickly look at what exactly each piece of code does, while at the same time knowing its spatial location (sort of a big detailed map in front of you) -- while methods are sorted alphabetically, scattered across classes in a browser, and when you want to look at what exactly this or that method does, you have to teleport between points in space discontinuously, which is harder for keeping orientation in space (like when you move between places in a city by underground trains without having a map of the city --

Comment: as opposed to moving by car, when you can see how those places are located relative to each other).

3) you have to spend time deleting all these intermediate methods after you finished your task (because these methods are not suited for reuse and you do not want them to clutter your image).

How would you comment on these problems from the point of view of experienced smalltalker?
@AmosM.Carpenter

Comment: What you're describing sounds like an _extreme edge case_ - I don't think many Smalltalk devs would have the problem you're describing, simply because, in my experience, they'd prefer to do things the "OO way", not the "huge script way". I can see where you're coming from, and hopefully someone knows the insides of how mouse scrolling works in Pharo and can help you, but my guess is that a) your script contains several comments that could just be _method names_, and b) those sets of variables you mention would make great _objects_. I just don't see a good reason to skimp on best practice.

Comment: You actually never want scrolling. You sometimes need it, but it is always inferior to being able to see all code at once. The smalltalk way is to have a specialized browser for this. There are several ones, depending on what you exactly need, e.g. the debugger with its stack trace, or Torsten's MessageFlowBrowser. With the plain class browser, having several open at the same time is normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing but a hack, rather than the right way to do it but what I've found is this:

```
vSetScrollDelta
  |pd|
  pd := self vPageDelta.
  self vScrollbar
    scrollDelta: pd / 50 "<- added / 50"
    pageDelta: pd;
    interval: self vScrollbarInterval;
    setValue: self vScrollbarValue
```

---

**EDIT**

I kept thinking that this answer would have been more useful if I told how I found the method above. It was really easy, and took me some few minutes (even though I'm not a Pharo user)

1. To get started I wrote down the word `scroll`. This was an obvious choice because the problem was about scrolling, right?
2. Then right-clicked to get the menu:

[image]

3. The `selectors containing it` command took me to this list

[image]

4. In that list the class `GeneralScrollPane` appeared many times so I browsed it. There I found the method `vScrollbarInterval` which looked promising. Right-clicked again to get its senders and `vSetScrollDelta` popped up, so I gave it a try.